Import Values Into JSON File In Webpack
I'm building an app with Webpack and need it to, among other things, emit a manifest.json file for PWA purposes. I want it to be built dynamically so it can get the asset URLs right for the icons (which would, ideally, then be included in the build) and, maybe, read values from other files (like read description from package.json). I've seen some plugins that allow for transformation of JSON files, but they seem to be for assigning static values instead of references to other files. Would I just have to build a whole custom plugin or loader for this?

you can use https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-manifest-plugin#compiler-hooks for example, if this is your understanding of a "manifest.json" file.

@madflow think they're different types of manifest files. In this case, I'm looking more for https://web.dev/articles/add-manifest

I'm contemplating writing a js/ts file that would produce the requisite object as the default export, which I could then stringify. The problem then is that I'd still have to create a loader that'd run the script to get the export as part of the build, as opposed to at app load time.

Soooo, I found a way to do this, but it doesn't seem like the correct solution... I built a manifest.json.ts file, which I have set to be run though ts-loader and a custom loader that resolves and builds the json at build-time, and finally set up as a resource asset in the root directory.
manifest.json.ts

import * as pkg from "/package.json";
import * as favIcon from "../static/images/favicon.ico";
import * as icon192 from "../static/images/icon-192.png";
import * as icon512 from "../static/images/icon-512.png";
import * as icon192Maskable from "../static/images/icon-192-maskable.png";
import * as icon512Maskable from "../static/images/icon-512-maskable.png";

export default {
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/master/src/schemas/json/web-manifest.json",
  "name": pkg?.title, 
  "short_name": pkg?.acronym, 
  "description": pkg?.description, 
  "theme_color": "#33557c", 
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF", 
  "display": "standalone", 
  "id": "/", 
  "start_url": "/", 
  "scope": "/", 
  "icons": [
    { "src": favIcon, "type": "image/x-icon", "sizes": "32x32" },
    { "src": icon192, "type": "image/png", "sizes": "192x192" },
    { "src": icon512, "type": "image/png", "sizes": "512x512" },
    { "src": icon192Maskable, "type": "image/png", "sizes": "192x192", "purpose": "maskable" },
    { "src": icon512Maskable, "type": "image/png", "sizes": "512x512", "purpose": "maskable" }
  ]
};

json-js-loader.js:

const scriptExtensionRemovalReg = /\.[cm]?[tj]s(\?.*)?$/i;

function getFileName(resourcePath) {
  return resourcePath.split(/[\/\\]/).pop();
}

module.exports.pitch = async function(remaining) {
  const targetResource = `${this.resourcePath}.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!${remaining}`;
  const result = await this.importModule(targetResource);

  const resultContent = JSON.stringify(result?.default || result);

  this._module.matchResource = getFileName(this.resourcePath).replace(scriptExtensionRemovalReg, "");

  this.resourcePath = this.resourcePath.replace(scriptExtensionRemovalReg, "");

  return resultContent;
}


webpack.config.js:
      //omitting previous loaders...
      {
        test: /\.json\.[cm]?[tj]s$/i, 
        type: "asset/resource", 
        generator: {
          filename: "[hash][ext][query]"
        },
        use: [ 
          path.resolve(__dirname, "build/json-js-loader.js"), 
          {
            loader: "ts-loader", 
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                module: "CommonJS", 
                rootDir: appFolder
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }

I did also have to modify my main typescript loader to exclude .json.ts files.
